PnP Search Results Display Calculated Column with "string;#" Preceeding Value
I'm using SharePoint Online PnP - Search Results to display metadata from a Document Library. The site column that I created is a calculated column that contains a string. I mapped that column to RefinableString05 and when I pull it into my Search Results, it renders "string;#" in front of the value.
Screenshot visible here: https://drexel0-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mfs28_drexel_edu/EbUJ1O4KPEFNtLiN0jQIDawBp1AyF3XRs7DCifU7OqeO1g?e=dEyKwP
I don't know why that is being added, as the metadata field in the Document Library only has what I would expect.
Screenshot visible here: https://drexel0-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mfs28_drexel_edu/EYQbfHPmSEhMgZeEh28VVSwBadUiP-33ucHWigVYX2pNnA?e=1RQ6JM
Any direction on how I can parse out the "string;#" value, either within SharePoint or using Handlebars for the rendering, would be most appreciated.
I am using Version 4.9.1 of the PnP - Search Results Web Part.

It looks like this works to remove the string from my calculated column value:
{{remove RefinableString05 "string;#"}}

If anyone else is having the same issue, this should help.
